# How to complete part of PhD in foreign lab but still get PhD from home insitution?

Tags: phd

I am doing my PhD work in India, but for my research work I wish to work in foreign lab conditions. So I wish to work in any of the foreign research institutes without quitting my current PhD work. What I mean exactly is I want a foreign guide as my co-investigator, whilst also getting a degree from my current institution.

Comment: The 'simple' way is to have a collaboration with another institute that allows you to visit for some months. The hard part is, of course, setting that up if your advisor does not currently have strong connections in place.

Comment: Aside from signing up for a dual-country PhD (where two institutions each grant you a separate PhD for the same body of work) you're limited to what @JonCuster days. Look in your literature, find which labs are working on things you know a bit about. Talk to your advisor, contact those PIs if s/he thinks it's a good idea. But in general, that's something that needs to be arranged early as it's a bit more difficult to do during the PhD. You'll be spending way too much time getting it prepped, and therefore less time for research.

Comment: How did your advisor answer this question? (You _did_ ask your advisor this question, didn't you?)

Answer (score 1):

Some scholarships will pay for you to attend a foreign university for a short period of time as part of your PhD, which will give you the chance to work with a foreign researcher in their lab. For example, if you'd like to attend a university in the US, you could try for the [Fulbright-Nehru Scholarship](http://www.usief.org.in/Fulbright-Nehru-Doctoral-Research-Fellowships.aspx), which will allow you to spend 6-9 months at a U.S. host institute.